# (How) can I use ServerSocket to listen for UDP instead of TCP traffic?

Tags: java, sockets

In my application, there's a module that uses `ServerSocket` to listen for incoming TCP connections. When I switched a client to use UDP, I expected to receive data anyway, but I was wrong. When I looked at the documentation, however, I couldn't find any config option to set up the socket for UDP. Do I have to use a different class?

Comment: You can't. Your question is basically malformed. Your question is really 'how can I listen for UDP traffic'. Specifying part of what you think is the answer as part of the question doesn't really work.

Comment: @EJP - That's why the "How" is in parentheses. The question is not malformed but exactly what I was wondering when I posted it: How can I do this (and can I do it at all)? It's in the post again, more explicitly: "Do I have to use a different class?" The prompt answer (just one minute later) was "you can't". So yes, it does work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use DatagramSocket. For a tutorial, look here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html