# Server in Java is not seeing broadcast udp packets

Tags: java, python, server, udp, broadcast

My project is composed by a server written in java and a client written in python and running on raspberry.

I'm trying to send a broadcast UDP message with raspberry pi in order to find the server in my network (its IP address change time by time so I can't set it by default) so that only the server will answer to my request and I can get its IP.

My client code is really simple:

```
import socket
import ssl
PORT=4435
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto("SERVER?", ("<broadcast>", PORT))
print(sock.recv(4096))
sock.close()
```

It simply open a socket and send the message "SOCKET?" in broadcast.

The server is simply too.
Class "Server":

```
public class Server extends Thread {

private ServerSocket server;

public ServerBroadcast() {
    try{  
       this.server= new ServerSocket(4435);
       System.out.println("Server is active");
       this.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Broadcast server is active!");
        while (true) {
            Socket richiestaClient = this.serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("received");
            new GestioneRichiesteBroadcast(richiestaClient);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Class "GestioneRichiesteBroadcast":
    public class GestioneRichiesteBroadcast {

```
private Socket connessione;
private Scanner input;
private PrintStream output;
private Date data;
private DateFormat formatoData;

public GestioneRichiesteBroadcast(Socket client) {
    try {
        this.connessione = client;
        this.input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        this.output = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
        this.data = new Date();
        this.formatoData = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
        this.gestioneRichiesta();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void gestioneRichiesta() {
    String messaggio = this.input.nextLine();
    if (messaggio.contentEquals("SERVER?")) {
        this.output.println("YES,"+this.formatoData.format(this.data));
    }
}
}
```

My server is not seeing the message sent by the client but Wireshark capture them and show them correctly. What am I wrong?

[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEUej.png)

Comment: In your server code: the ServerSocket class is used for TCP, not UDP.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051834/how-can-i-use-serversocket-to-listen-for-udp-instead-of-tcp-traffic

Comment: Thanks, I never used UDP in Java and I thought I could use the same object. Now it works fine!